# Ising Model 2D Python

Tags: python, physics, montecarlo

I've coded out the Ising Model simulation based on Monte Carlo simulation and the Metropolis Algorithm but I am having some trouble, namely the `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

The following shows where the error lies in the code:

[image: The image embedded shows where the error lies in the code].

If anyone spots any other errors that may inhibit the code from producing the graphs then please let me know.

```
# Code Mark 1.4: Ising Model in 2D

# Importing all the necessary packages I will use:
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as rnd

# Before I do anything I need to make sure the specifics of the size of the lattice as a 12x12 sized, number of steps, number of temperature points used, number of points in order to reach an equilibrium state are all accounted for
num=16 
steps_monte=100
temp_points=50 
steps_equil=100 
num_a=1/(steps_monte*(num**2))
num_b=1/((steps_monte**2)*(num**2))

# Next I must create an intitial spin state for my molecule: 
def startspin(num):   
    spin=rnd.randint(2,size=(num,num))-1
    return spin

# Now I need to define the energy function. This will give the energy of any given spin state:
def Energy(Q):
    starting_energy=0
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        for j in range(len(Q)):
            g=Q[i,j]
            n_y=Q[(i+1)%num,j]+Q[i,(j+1)%num]+Q[(i-1)%num,j]+Q[i,(j-1)%num]
            starting_energy+=g*-n_y
    return starting_energy/4

# Now I need to code the Monte Carlo Steps with Metro ALgorithm for the ising model:
def montestep(Q,P):
    for i in range(num):
        for j in range(num):
                x=rnd.randint(0,num)
                y=rnd.randint(0,num)
                z=Q[x,y]
                n_y=Q[(x+1)%num,y]+Q[x,(y+1)%num]+Q[(x-1)%num,y]+Q[x,(y-1)%num]
                l=2*z*n_y
                if l<0:
                    z*=-1
                elif rnd.rand()<np.exp(P*-l):
                    z*=-1
                Q[x,y]=z
    return Q

#Now I need to define the magnetization function. This gives the Magnetization of any given spin state:
def Magnetization(Q):
    magnetization=np.sum(Q)
    return magnetization

# Here I am saying that the temperature points need to have a midpoint where we expect the disorder to begin and to give us random points between this value as 1<T<5
temp_mid = 2.25;    
Temp=rnd.normal(temp_mid,0.5,temp_points)
Temp=Temp[(Temp>1)&(Temp<5)]   
temp_points=np.size(Temp)

# I need to define 0 points for each of the 4 physical quantities I wish to find:
Magnetization=np.zeros(temp_points)
SpecificHeat=np.zeros(temp_points)  
Energy=np.zeros(temp_points)
Susceptibility=np.zeros(temp_points)

# Now I need to implement each function above by creating an Ising Function with them:
for j in range(len(Temp)):
    E_a=M_a=0
    E_b=M_b=0
    Q=startspin(num)
    init_Temp_a=1/Temp[j] 
    init_Temp_b=init_Temp_a**2

    for i in range(steps_monte):
        montestep(Q,init_Temp_a)            
        Energy_calc=Energy[Q]  
        Mag_calc=Magnetization[Q]       
        E_a=E_a+(Energy_calc)
        M_a=M_a+(Mag_calc)
        M_b=M_b+(Mag_calc**2)
        E_b=E_b+(Energy_calc**2)
        Energy[j]=num_a*E_a[i][j]
        Magnetization[j]=num_a*M_a[i][j]
        SpecificHeat[j]=(num_a*E_b[i][j]-num_b*(E_a[i][j]**2))*init_Temp_b
        Susceptibility[j]=(num_a*M_b[i][j]-num_b*(M_a[i][j]**2))*init_Temp_a

    for k in range(steps_equil):        
        montestep(Q,init_Temp_a)   

#Finally I can plot the 4 graphs I need to show the monte carlo steps of the ising model and can then conduct my research thereafter.

plt.plot(T, Energy,'d', color="#8A2BE2")
plt.xlabel("Temperature (Kelvin)")
plt.ylabel("Energy (Arbitrary Units)")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, abs(Magnetization),'x', color="#7FFF00")
plt.xlabel("Temperature (Kelvin)")
plt.ylabel("Magnetization (Arbitrary Units)")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, SpecificHeat, 'd', color="#00FFFF")
plt.xlabel("Temperature (Kelvin)")
plt.ylabel("Specific Heat (Arbitrary Units)")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, Susceptibility, 'x', color="#0000FF")
plt.xlabel("Temperature (Kelvin)")
plt.ylabel("Susceptibility (Arbitrary Units)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Thomas8 OP seems to indicate there's an obvious error in this code. Which means it's most definitely a big no-no to post it on Code Review. Code Review only accepts working code.

Comment: For what version is this written, Python 2.7?

Comment: @Mast it was written in Jupyter Notebook 5.0.0. I think it uses python 3.6

Comment: Right. I found the problem, you'll have my answer shortly.

Comment: Turns out there are multiple problems. Are you sure you've uploaded the most recent version of your code? On line 77, you're referencing `E`. `E` is undefined. If Jupyter doesn't catch that, it's seriously flawed.

Comment: Line 78 in the picture doesn't correspond to line 78 in the code.

Comment: @Mast apologies I'll rectify this now

Comment: @Mast It should be the same now

Answer (score 1):

What you could've done to find this error:

```
print(type(Energy[j]), type(num_a), type(E_a))
```

Right before you set `Energy[j]`. You'll find it out isn't going to work:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'> <class 'float'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

`E_a` is a numpy array. You can't assign an array to a value that has to resolve to a float. I'm not familiar with the algorithm, but perhaps you wanted to use the following instead?

```
Energy[j]= num_a * E_a[i][j]
```

You'll find the same thing goes wrong for setting `Magnetization[j]` a little later on. Same problem, same fix.

This solves the problem on my machine, running Python 3.5.2. The code still has issues though. For example, `num_b` is referenced twice but never created.

EDIT: renaming `num_2` to `num_b` and `M1` to `M_a`, there are a couple more errors. Basically your function could be looking like this:

```
for i in range(len(Temp)):
    E_a=M_a=0
    E_b=M_b=0
    Q=startspin(num)
    init_Temp_a=1/Temp[i] 
    init_Temp_b=init_Temp_a**2

    for j in range(steps_monte):
        montestep(Q,init_Temp_a)            
        Energy_calc=Energy[Q]  
        Mag_calc=Magnetization[Q]       
        E_a=E_a+(Energy_calc)
        M_a=M_a+(Mag_calc)
        M_b=M_b+(Mag_calc**2)
        E_b=E_b+(Energy_calc**2)
        print(E_a[i][j])
        Energy[j]= num_a * E_a[i][j]
        Magnetization[j]=num_a*M_a[i][j]
        SpecificHeat[j]=(num_a*E_b[i][j]*(E_a[i][j]**2))*init_Temp_b
        Susceptibility[j]=(num_a*M_b[i][j]*(M_a[i][j]**2))*init_Temp_a

    for _ in range(steps_equil):        
        montestep(Q,init_Temp_a)
```

But that shows something much more problematic. Take a look at the following:

```
for i in range(len(Temp)):
for j in range(steps_monte):
```

`steps_monte` is set to 1024, the length of `Temps` appears to be non-constant (but above 250). So this will be iterating over a lot of values, right? Well, not really. Because the arrays it's iterating over aren't that big. So the iteration will go out of bounds. The array stops earlier than the iteration.

Which makes me wonder whether the algorithm implementation isn't flawed in a much bigger way.

*Note:* your code uses `j` before `i`. I switched that around, which is a more common notation and easier to understand.

Comment: ok thank you I'll go back and work on it. I see where the num_b problem arises it was marked num_2 when created thank you for bringing it to my attention

Comment: IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12 is now showing up when I run my updated code. This is directly related to my:num=12 line but I'm not quite sure why its out of bounds even when I change it

Comment: @OisinBrannock Arrays are 0-indexed. Your first (1) number is on location zero (0).

Comment: @OisinBrannock Oh, and you're iterating till 1024. So it runs out way before reaching that.

Comment: Any number I run seems to pop up with the same error I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Comment: @OisinBrannock Think about what your for loop is doing. How often does it iterate? What does it access? steps_monte is way too high for what you do. I suspect there's a more fundamental problem with your implementation.

Comment: @ Even changing the values to very small quantities still returns the same indexing error

Comment: @OisinBrannock Yes, because you're iterating till Temp and steps_monte. Those two values are either way too high, or you're iterating to the wrong values.

Comment: I'm really not sure what values to use in order to get rid of this error I'm afraid

Comment: @OisinBrannock Let's phrase it differently. Why did you set up your code the way you set it up? Do you have a flow-chart or something you based it on?

Comment: I think I need to do more research around the actual values before I can implement them effectively. I see what you're saying and it's helping greatly much appreciated